# how add fa-fa icon in checkbox but it must appears at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

suppose to have a dropdown menu and I want that when I clinck on the menu I see the checkbox, the label and at the end the fa-fa icon.This is my jquery code when I put the checkbox on the menu:

```
$('#ul_menu').append('<li><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungi' + user_bookmarked[i].nome_bookmarked + '">     ' + user_bookmarked[i].nome_bookmarked + '<i class="fa fa-lock fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>');
```

I see the "fa fa-lock" attached to the checkbox label I want to appears at the end of the menu. Anyone can help me?

THIS IS MY HTML CODE:

```
div class="btn-group open"><button id="bookmarked_button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" type="button"><span class="visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline">Bookmarked</span><span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="ul_menu"><li><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungidsfsdf" checked="">        dsfsdf</li><li><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungiasdas">     asdas<i class="fa fa-lock fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="aggiungicollaborativo">        collaborativo<i class="fa fa-lock fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></li><li><a href="#" id="aggiungi_bookmarked"><i class="fa fa-fw fa fa-plus"></i>Aggiungi Bookmarked</a></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Prpvide your html to?

Comment: Can you share any working demo. Like: jsfiddle.net or similar

Comment: I have put the code in a JS Fiddle and l can see the fa-lock being appended to the end of the menu item. 
https://jsfiddle.net/mattlaza/0kdrcx2g/

Comment: Can the `<ul>` have a width? If yes, we can add a `float:right;` style to the `<li>` tags. I tried updating the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/0kdrcx2g/3/ . I also added `fa-fw` class to the icons for fixed width.